# Can't extract value of XML nodes with powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm trying to extract some info from an xml file and update/create an app pool as needed. Here's the xml I'm reading in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appPool name="MyAppPool">
  <enable32BitAppOnWin64>true</enable32BitAppOnWin64>
  <managedPipelineMode>Integrated</managedPipelineMode>
  <managedRuntimeVersion>v4.0</managedRuntimeVersion>
  <autoStart>true</autoStart>
</appPool>
```

Here's what I'm trying to do with it:

```
#read in the xml
$appPoolXml = [xml](Get-Content $file)

#get the name of the app pool
$name = $appPoolXml.appPool.name

#iterate over the nodes and update the app pool
$appPoolXml.appPool.ChildNodes | % {
     #this is where the problem exists
     set-itemproperty IIS:\AppPools\$name -name $_.Name -value $_.Value
}
```

`$_.Name` returns the name of the node, (i.e. `enable32BitAppOnWin64`) which is correct, but the `.Value` property doesn't return anything. How do I extract the data I want?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Corrected answer:

You want `$_.'#text'` instead of `$_.Value`.

Consider this also, which uses the `InnerText` property on the `System.Xml.XmlElement` objects:

$xml.appPool.ChildNodes | % { $*.Name; $*.InnerText };

Comment: Actually the correct PowerShell should read `$appPoolXml.appPool.ChildNodes | % {  $_.Name; $_.InnerText }`

Comment: Note that InnerText gets all the text under a node, such that ([xml]"<xml>foo<bar>bar</bar></xml>").xml.InnerText returns "foobar", whereas you probably want "foo".(...).

xml.'#text' returns "foo".